# Read CSV file in Hive 0.13 without quotes and comma in data as well

Tags: sql, regex, csv, hive, cloudera

How to read read a comma delimited file in Hive version 0.13 when the data itself contains comma and the fields doesn't have quote character. example
fname,lname,country, city, addr, dob are the column names,

```
tom, kate, USA,CA,los angeles,34 brad street 5thfloor, Jun/23/1975
russel,smith,USA, Tx, 763, grass street, 5th floor, dallas, Jan/31/1999
```

first line doesn't have any columns with comma in the data
second line in the address field there are commas in the data
**763, grass street, 5th floor, dallas**

how to read this in hive 0.13 version

thanks
Mx

Comment: it should be properly formatted "FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS " else it will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `addr` is the only field that might contain a comma

```
create external table mydata
(
    fname       string
   ,lname       string
   ,country     string
   ,city        string
   ,addr        string
   ,dob         string
)
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
with serdeproperties ("input.regex" = "(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*),(.*)")
location '/user/hive/warehouse/mydata'
;
```

---

```
select * from mydata;
```

---

```
+--------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+
| mydata.fname | mydata.lname | mydata.country | mydata.city | mydata.addr                          | mydata.dob  |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+
| tom          | kate         | USA            | CA          | los angeles,34 brad street 5thfloor  | Jun/23/1975 |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+
| russel       | smith        | USA            | Tx          | 763, grass street, 5th floor, dallas | Jan/31/1999 |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+
```